# Allow natural back button behaviour with use case of dynamically-added query parameters

Tags: vue.js, router, vuex, back, nuxt.js

I have the case that I push some parameters to the nuxt router (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) whenever somebody visits a page without any parameters.

Example:
somebody visits: `/program` it will end up in `/program/first-event?year=2018&month=6`
(First the view filters the program for current events (therefore the parameters for this year and this month) and then from the filtered events it will set the first event as active post (also by pushing it to the router).

This is all wanted and good. BUT now I detected the following problem:
Somebody is visiting `/aboutus` and then navigates to `/program`, the router will automatically change to `/program/url-of-event-post?year=2018&month=6`.
Assuming the user wants to go back to `/aboutus` he clicks on the browser back button. This will bring him back to: `/program` which automatically adds the post and the parameters again (effectively moving one step forward again).

Means the user is caught in clicking endlessly on the back button.
My approach would be to try to register if a user clicks on the back button and if so, I would not add the parameters. But I don't know how to do this.
I thought the router would provide some 'from' property, but so far I did not find anything.

I would be very happy to hear some thoughts on this. Thank you heaps in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `router.replace`.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-replace-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: Oh that's sounds good. I will try it. Thanks a lot!
Important is taht this will also trigger a router change, when watching the router, but I guess it will and I will report back here :D

Comment: Worked like a charm by the way!

Comment: @Merc can you post your actual solution to this issue?

Comment: @podcastfan88 Sorry I somehow never got informed about your post. I also see that 6 people would have an interest in that... So years later: `this.$router.replace({ path: \`/${this.page.slug}/${firstPostInFuture.slug}\`, query: this.$route.query })`. Something like this. Worth mentioning: the page's slug = `program` whereas I have a computed property that returns the slug for the first post in the future. In my example here, I just copy the  current queries, but if you want somethin like the `year` `month` queries, just add them instead to your query object.
I hope that helps.

Comment: This solution doesn't match the original title of this question.